# Matlab no legend colors

Tags: matlab, legend

does anybody know why the legend does not matches the colors of the plot but is instead just black?

```
figure;
plot(noActivity,0,'ko',lowActivity,0,'go',medActivity,0,'bo',highActivity,0,'ro');
hold on;
legend('no activity','low activity','medium activity','high activity');
stairs(integrals);
```

And this is what it looks like:
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: my guess is that for each element of `noActivity`, `lowActivity`, etc. one `Line` is created, and `noActivity` has 4 or more elements. Thus only these are shown in the legend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one of the `X` or `Y` arguments is a scalar, [`plot` will create as many `Line` plot objects as there are elements in the other argument](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html#btzitot-1):

> If one of X or Y is a scalar and the other is either a scalar or a
>   vector, then the plot function plots discrete points. However, to see
>   the points you must specify a marker symbol, for example,
>   plot(X,Y,'o').

Therefore, since according to the attached plot `noActivity` has more than 4 elements, the first four elements of the legend have the same style. (You can verify this by assigning the output of `plot` to a variable, which will be as long as all the four data vectors combined and contain one `Line` object per data point).

An easy workaround would be to write

```
plot(noActivity, zeros(size(noActivity)), 'ko', ...
    lowActivity, zeros(size(lowActivity)), 'go', ...
    medActivity, zeros(size(medActivity)), 'bo', ...
    highActivity, zeros(size(highActivity)), 'ro');
```

instead. This should also be faster and memory efficient, because only four plot objects will be created.